# Cannot apply values to list C# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, list, class

Returning information from webservice. I have made a class for the return object. But I get the following error message when assigning results to each list item.

When invoking my webservice I am returned with the following message:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
>   NewUser.ADMethods.GetUserInfo(String userName)

Please help!

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public string givenname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }            
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<UserInformation> GetUserInfo(string userName)
{
    // Gather User Info
    // Invoke Directory Searcher & Directory Entry
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
    // Apply filter to search
    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(samaccountname=" + userName + "))";

        SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
        List<UserInformation> UserInfo = new List<UserInformation>();
        UserInfo[0].givenname = sr.Properties["givenname"].ToString();
        return UserInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a list, which is initially empty, and then trying to access value for a first item, which does not exist yet.

You have to create the item and then add it to the list:

```
List<UserInformation> UserInfo = new List<UserInformation>();
UserInformation item = new UserInformation();
item.givenname = sr.Properties["givenname"].ToString();
UserInfo.Add(item);
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Why would a list need to contain information, prior to adding my values to it? - Sorry NOW I UNDERSTAND :)

Comment: Your method returns a list of `UserInformation`. Thus, you need to fill that list, even though you only return the first found.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
List<UserInformation> UserInfo = new List<UserInformation>(); 
UserInfo[0].givenname = sr.Properties["givenname"].ToString();
```

You are creating a new List, with no entries, and then directly after that you try to acces the first entry, which does not exist.